# "В ночном небе нет комет, Вся планета в мире снов."

Tags: узус

I can understand the first part of the sentence, it is:

There is no comet in the night sky.

But the second part confuses me, how to translate this part? is снов the genitive case?

It comes from here:

http://www.mumiytroll.com/inc/song_text.php?id=69&title=%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: снов is genitive plural of сон.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**В мире снов means** "in the world of dreams". Снов from сны is a noun in the genitive. Вся планета в мире снов (The whole planet is in the world of dreams= The planet is sleeping).Комет is also in the genitive plural.

Comment: and, to complete the answer, сны is the plural of сон (dream). the stressed О disappears in all cases besides nominative singular.